# Codeigniter: Sum value of several columns

Tags: codeigniter, sum

I simply need to sum the value of about 15 columns (say, 20-35) in codeigniter.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do it exactly the same way you would in plain SQL. If MySQL then you can do this:

```
$this->db->select('SUM(field1) + SUM(field2) + SUM(field3) as total', FALSE);
```

The FALSE stops auto-escaping.